# What is the Thickness of JIS Standard Pipe

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, standards

I work in engineering company that doing pipe installation. Just now our company got inquiry from Japanese company. They ask me to manufacture a pipe for exhaust ducting. The thing is they use Japanese standard (JIS). The size that they want to make is 150A, 250A, and 600A. My question is what is the thickness of these pipe?

Comment: Specified in the JIS standard? Do you have a copy?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately I don't. That's why I'm checking if only there are?

Answer (score 0):

You need the JIS standard. When you have the dimensions you will find they very likely correlate to ASTM / NPS dimensions.

Comment: Do you know where can I get the copy ?